# Need example of updating set data in Linq

Tags: linq, intersection

I have two sets of data where I need to update one set from another.  I have a large set of data so need to find an efficient way to do this.

```
public class Data
{
    int id {get; set;}
    string comment {get; set;}
}
public class DataComments
{
    int id {get; set;}
    string comment {get; set;}
}
```

I have 2 collections, one of Data and another of DataComments.  e.g. List.  I need to update class "Data" with comments found in the List collection if it exists.  When complete I need all rows in Data and have it's comment property updated if there's a intersection in DataComments.  Bottom line I just need to update one set of data from another if there's anything found.  I thought the intersection might be a way to do this.

Comment: The Q in LinQ means Query, so LinQ might be helpful, but not a complete solution. Inserting or Updating is not in the scope of LinQ.

Comment: OK, well I'll ask another way.  How can I emit a NEW list?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the `query2` object to a list by calling `query2.ToList()` and it will return a list of the anonymous type you've created.  If you want to use it elsewhere in your code, you need a new POCO object that you can create in your query, and return the list of that object.

So, in your case your query should look like:

```
var query2 = modelRows.GroupJoin(commentRows, 
     gridRow => gridRow.NSN, commentRow => commentRow.NSN, 
    (gridRow, cg) => new ModelRowsGroupObject {
                    NSN = gridRow.NSN,
                    CommentGroup = cg,
                    Desc = gridRow.Desc

                }).ToList();
```

Somewhere else in your code, define a ModelRowsGroupObject as a plain old CLR object, and you're good to go.